# Usage of "the same as in" and "the same as of"

Tags: prepositions, idiomatic-language

The following sentence is on [an article of Khan Academy](https://www.khanacademy.org/math/geometry/hs-geo-circles/hs-geo-radians-intro/a/arcs-ratios-and-radians):

> 1. "Which properties of circle B are the same as in circle A?"

I thought the following sentences may have the same meaning as above:

2. Which properties **of** circle B are the same as **of** circle A?
3. Which properties **in** circle B are the same as **in** circle A?
4. Which properties **in** circle B are the same as **of** circle A?

My question is:

- Do you think each sentence is correct and natural?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It should really be "of" not "in" for both, as long as it does not actuallly *mean* "in".

"A property of x" denotes that "x has the property", "the property belongs to x" which is the case when you are discussing mathematical objects.

Comment: Thank you for answering. Do you think the sentence 2 are correct and natural? @David Siegel seems to find "the same as of" in the sentence incorrect.(https://ell.stackexchange.com/a/270455/127344)

Comment: @user13651701 "the same as those of" is probably better.

Answer (score 2):

Sentence 2 strikes me as awkward at best. "...the same as of circle A" just feels incorrect at the second "of"."same as of" just does not work, in my view.

Sentence 3 seems correct, but different in meaning. "Properties in circle A"  would seem to  be properties included in A, not aspects of A.

Sentence 4 has the same problem as 2, plus the same issue with "properties in" as 3.

I would recast 1 as:

> "Which properties of circle B are also properties of circle A?
> .